# Is it possible to create a LyX Layout Style without vertical paragraph spacing?

Tags: lyx, lyx-layouts

When i define a new `Style` in a LyX Layout, in the LaTeX output there is always two newlines after the LyX paragraph.

I can remove the vertical spacing which is displayed inside the LyX editor (with `TopSep`, `BottomSep` and `TopSep`), but i'm unable to figure out how to avoid the `\n\n` in the LaTeX output which causes a paragraph spacing:

```
Style NoSpacingParagraph
    CopyStyle             Standard
    TopSep                0
    BottomSep             0
    ParSep                0
End
```

I've already tried a custom `LatexName` with a self-defined latex command - but the `\n\n` seems to be unavoidable.

Any ideas?

Comment: this question helped me to find the answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/242294/suppress-parskip-only-after-a-specific-paragraph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In LaTeX, the parskip *following* a paragraph can be removed by appending a negative vertical space with the length of a parskip (`\vspace{-\parskip}`)  to the end of it. The negative spacing and the positive parskip then eliminate each other.

To incorporate this solution into a LyX paragraph style, i used the following:

```
Style NoSpacingParagraph
        CopyStyle             Standard
        LatexType             Command
        LatexName             noparskip
        TopSep                0.0
        ParSep                0.0
        BottomSep             0.0
        ParSkip               0.0
        Preamble
                \newcommand{\noparskip}[1]{#1\vspace{-\parskip}}
        EndPreamble
End
```

Now just select this new style for a paragraph and the parskip between it and the following paragraph disappears in the rendered output.

The answer is inspired by this question: [Suppress parskip only AFTER a specific paragraph?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/242294/suppress-parskip-only-after-a-specific-paragraph)

Comment: This is quite a poor answer for the following reasons: (1) Specifying a paragraph to have this `NoSpacingParagraph` style only *defines* a macro called `\noparskip`, but never uses it. You're still forced to insert `\noparskip` as an ERT, correct? That is, you never show it's proper usage. (2) Why does `\noparskip` take an argument? (3) You emphasize that the "following" paragraph will have a different `\parskip`... in that sense you're only referring to the `\parskip` at the top of some paragraph, not the bottom as well.

Comment: (4) Issuing `\noparskip` inside a paragraph technically implies you're issuing a "vertical command" inside "horizontal mode". As such it is stored until "vertical mode" is entered next. So you're issuing a command that doesn't have any meaning where it's used.

Comment: @Werner (1) This is what `LatexType Command` and `LatexName noparskip` are used for. The command is automatically applied to all paragraphs that are of style `NoSpacingPragraph` (2) see 1. the parameter is the content of the paragraph (3) the following paragraph will still have a normal parskip. formula: `current paragraphs negative vspace + normal parskip = 0pt` (4) the vertical skip is appended after paragraph before `\n\n`, which is the exact point where latex is entering vertical mode.

Comment: @Werner maybe you should just try it out and look at the resulting latex code and the resulting rendered output. Also, take a look at this question where things might get more clear. It has more focus on the LaTeX details instead of the complexity LyX adds to the problem: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/242294/suppress-parskip-only-after-a-specific-paragraph

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of `LatexType` and `LatexName`.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have defined a validated *local* layout (Document > Settings... > Local Layout) it adds this as an option to the formatting dropdown/toolbar:

[image]

Seeing as you're using a "copy" of the `Standard` style to create `NoSpacingParagraph`, you still need to select the paragraphs which should be set using `NoSpacingParagraph`. Alternatively, you need to change `Standard` directly as a local layout (overriding it).

Here is the `Standard` style (taken from `stdclass.inc`):

```
Style Standard
    Category              MainText
    Margin                Static
    LatexType             Paragraph
    LatexName             dummy
    ParIndent             MM
    ParSkip               0.4
    Align                 Block
    AlignPossible         Block, Left, Right, Center
    LabelType             No_Label
    # FIXME This ought to be set dynamically.
    HTMLStyle
        div.standard {
            margin-bottom: 2ex;
        }
    EndHTMLStyle
End
```

Secondly, the LaTeX output has a paragraph gap/skip defined by the variable `\parskip`. If you have a large `\parskip` defined somewhere, this may be the cause. It could also be easily overwritten by adding

```
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\parskip}{<your choice>}}
```

to your Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble.

Comment: @Kaii: You didn't mention that you want it removed for a specific paragraph. Next time, be specific in terms of your question.

Comment: @Kaii: Adding a single style doesn't mean it pertains to a single paragraph, since documents typically contain multiple paragraphs in general.

Comment: FWIW: i wrote that i wanted to create a specific style, which may apply to one or many (but not all) paragraphs inside the document. I never meant to apply it to a single paragraph, and never meant to apply it globally. What should be rephrased in my question exactly?